# Double buffering and scrolling with Cairo (pygobject)

Tags: python, cairo

I am using `cairo` with `pygobject` for drawing into a `Gtk.DrawingArea`.

The drawing is expensive so I first draw to a `cairo.ImageSurface` and then use that as source to paint in the draw event callback. Updating the drawing only when needed.

Now suppose I want to shift the image to the left, that is, copy it to itself but translated, adding new content on the right.

`123456789`  `->`  `456789NEW`

I think is not possible to do that directly.

A way around I came up is to have two `ImageSurface` and in each scroll copy from one to the other and switch places.

something like:

```
cr = cairo.Context(buffer_aux)
cr.set_source(buffer)
cr.translate(dx, dy)
cr.paint()
cr.flush()
buffer, buffer_aux = buffer_aux, buffer
```

Is that the correct way to go o I am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

> I think is not possible to do that directly.

Correct. I do not have any source to point to for this claim, but I think that self-copies in cairo are forbidden.

There is a test case in cairo which tests this, but I was once told that it only exists since there was once an endless loop involved. So, this test actually tests "finishes and does not crash" and does not check the resulting rendering.